# Is there any harm in using amazon AWS as a development environment?

Tags: web-development, ruby-on-rails, cloud-computing, aws

What modifications do I need to make to my workflow, and which skills do I need to learn in order to develop with Ruby On Rails on a Linux cloud server on Amazon Web Services (AWS)?

In particular, I am concerned that it won't work, or it will be much more difficult than developing on my Windows netbook, which is adequate for PHP development with XAMP.

Comment: Running a local web server for development (i.e. one user) should be trivial for any but the most underpowered systems. Are you using a netbook or tablet?

Comment: @Snowman So you are suggesting to use aws.I wanted a production like environment for my development.I use a netbook.

Comment: That makes sense, then. I understand the convenience of lightweight systems like that and I use them myself, but not for development. In my opinion those are _consumption_ devices for _using_ content, not for creating it. I have an Ultrabook for when I need to develop on the go.

Comment: I think the OP didn't ask us to recommend a tool. He chose a tool and asked if it was adequate. Tools are explicitly on topic: it is only the recommendations that are off topic.

Comment: I thought the question was OK

Comment: I use an EC2 instance for development in my current project, because it provides a known environment: I can control exact versions of frameworks and installed software, and I can ensure that my development machine config exactly matches production config. And I ensure that the configuration for one project does not "pollute" my laptop going into a new project. As a side benefit, I think working on EC2 with a scripted install gets you into the habit of "throw the old one away" whenever you change configs, rather than attempting to maintain a single system (and not *knowing* what it runs).

Answer (score 2):

No - there is no harm in using an AWS Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) instance for your development platform.

But you will have to learn some extra skills that you wouldn't need when developing on a local machine

- how to use [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](https://aws.amazon.com/security/),
- how to use AWS billing (if you exceed the one year free micro instance), and
- [how to use SSH.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html)

It is just as easy to run a Linux virtual machine to develop in Rails, or indeed to develop in another operating system such as FreeBSD, Mac OS X and Windows. Virtual machines can be slow on a netbook, but native development is often acceptable. RoR doesn't require much more resources than XAMP, but it depends on your application, so you will have to try it and see.

An AWS micro instance has similar power to a netbook (as of 2015.)

Comment: I have used amazon AWS earlier.I am starting my development on amazon aws.Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: One additional bullet point: you will need to learn basic server security. If you expose your server to the open Internet, it will be pounded by crackerbots. Learn to use security groups to restrict access to specific IP addresses. And *never* enable password-based authentication or direct root login.